# Unknown PSU blown capacitor

Tags: capacitor, properties

[image][image]

Hi,
I have a 1988 laptop with a blown PSU capacitor (was located in c10).
The capacitor still barely reads 395 (which an online calculator says means 3.9uf) and +35k which means 35v(?).

1) How important is it to replace the capacitor I have with one of the same characteristics?

2) How important is it to have the replacement capacitor a tantalum one?

Thanks.[image]

Comment: Most probably low given the voltage rating and the 1988 vintage. I would just try it. 4.7 uF will be more standard than 3.9. Is everything else around it intact?

Comment: If you don't use a tantalum for replacement, you'll never see the pretty fire again.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
Regarding everything else being intact. This blown capacitor is a follow up to a twice blown, twice replaced bigger capacitor. Connecting the PSU to a 240v -> 120v transformator seems to have helped (this wasnt mandatory as the PSU is cross voltage but felt better to do this move).

I think im going to do exactly what you advice. Will order some 4.7uf / 35v's.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

To both of your questions, how important it is to have

1) same characteristics
2) same type of chemistry

there is no definitive answer. It really depends on what the capacitor was doing in the circuit. It is not possible know that just by looking a picture.